# Extraer valores de una Colección (IEnumerable) hacia un array

Tags: c#, linq, wpf, collection

Disculpen tengo cierto codigo que tiene la funcion de generar un ListView -> grid a partir de un archivo csv el cual esta funcionando correctamente, mi problema seria que necesito obtener los valores de las columnas en este caso (Directorio, Nombre, Evento, Tipo, etc  ) y guardarlos en una estructura tipo array o list para poder ser tratados con consultas de Linq y generar otro tipo de vista/grafico. He tratado muchas cosas pero no he podido extraer los valores de la clase Person.
Como dato extra estoy utilizando WPF.

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Directorio { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Evento { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public string Tamaño { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public Person(string directorio, string nombre, string evento, string tipo, string tamaño, string time, string path)
        {
            Directorio = directorio;
            Nombre = nombre;
            Evento = evento;
            Tipo = tipo;
            Tamaño = tamaño;
            Time = time;
            Path = path;
        }
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public IEnumerable<Person> ReadCSV(string fileName)
        {
            
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".csv"));
            return lines.Select(line =>
            {
                string[] data = line.Split(',');             
                return new Person(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6]) ;
             
            });
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListViewPeople.ItemsSource = ReadCSV(@"D:\dato.csv");
          
        }
    }
```

Comment: puedes serializar los datos de tu csv con una librería de manejo de texto como http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

Comment: No entiendo tu problema, pues en esta linea de código `string[] data = line.Split(',');`  ya estas obteniendo los datos de un objeto `Person` en una estructura tipo array.

Comment: @EduardoReyes, Claro en esa parte del código dentro de `public IEnumerable<Person> ReadCSV(string fileName)` pude manejar esos tipo de datos pero fuera de el no existían, podía aplicar las consultas que necesitaba pero no me reflejaban en el MainWindow.

Comment: Y no puedes crear una variable de tipo array, con alcance global al nivel de `MainWindow` y en ella almacenar el dato que necesitas, desde dentro de `public IEnumerable<Person> ReadCSV(string fileName)` o en ves de devolver  `IEnumerable<Person>`, devolver un array `public string[] ReadCSV(string fileName)`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
        public string[] ReadCSV(string fileName)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".csv"));
            return lines.Select(line =>
            {
                return  line.Split(','); 
            });
        }
```